# Eclipse Package Explorer Not Displaying Properly

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

When I select the "Package Explorer" tab, I get a vast white space with only the top of my 10 projects showing up, and not on the left side of the pane like it should, but instead on the right side. It's weird. If I click on it, I get a "Problem Occurred" pop box saying "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Could not initialize class org.container.directory.Logger".

The error message in /.metadata/.log is this:

---

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-09-25 13:36:17.223
>   !MESSAGE Unable to create class
>   'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' from
>   bundle '568' !STACK 0 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:839)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:896)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:630)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:518)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:503)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:896)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:630)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4291)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$8.widgetSelected(StackRenderer.java:910)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1300)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1285)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1079)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.container.directory.ContainerDirFilter.select(ContainerDirFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.isFiltered(ProblemTreeViewer.java:321)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$PackageExplorerProblemTreeViewer.isFiltered(PackageExplorerPart.java:279)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.containsNonFiltered(ProblemTreeViewer.java:302)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.hasFilteredChildren(ProblemTreeViewer.java:266)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.isExpandable(ProblemTreeViewer.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.updatePlus(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2858)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.updatePlus(TreeViewer.java:852)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:849)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:823)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:797)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:768)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:833)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1532)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1525)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.createPartControl(PackageExplorerPart.java:509)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>     ... 78 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Logging
>   bundle must not be null.  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.(Log.java:30)     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPlatform.java:356)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getLog(Platform.java:1004)     at
>   org.container.directory.Logger.(Logger.java:28)   ... 111 more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2013-09-25 13:36:18.255 !MESSAGE Problems
>   occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface". !STACK
>   0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.container.directory.Logger    at
>   org.container.directory.ContainerDirFilter.select(ContainerDirFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.isFiltered(ProblemTreeViewer.java:321)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$PackageExplorerProblemTreeViewer.isFiltered(PackageExplorerPart.java:279)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.containsNonFiltered(ProblemTreeViewer.java:302)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.hasFilteredChildren(ProblemTreeViewer.java:266)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.isExpandable(ProblemTreeViewer.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.getSelectionFrame(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.framelist.TreeViewerFrameSource.getFrame(TreeViewerFrameSource.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.framelist.GoIntoAction.getSelectionFrame(GoIntoAction.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.framelist.GoIntoAction.update(GoIntoAction.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup$2.selectionChanged(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:161)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

---

It appears to be related to org.container.directory.Logger. "Logging bundle must not be null." Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out how to fix it, but I have observed that it only occurs when I have a Servers project in my workspace - I suspect it has something to do with the fact that that project doesn't have a classpath...

Answer (score 1):

There is the File `DirectoryClasspathContainer_1.0.0_EclipsePlugin.jar` in `C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins`. Delete the file.